# Can't cd into 770 directory even though I'm in the group - complicated by IPA

Tags: linux, freeipa

Boy howdy, I'm kind of scratching my head over this.

I have a directory with 770 permissions:

```
inger@server$> ls -ld mydir
drwxrwx--- 2 root mygroup1 4096 May 22 05:27 mydir
```

I can't `cd` into it:

```
inger@server$> cd mydir
-bash: cd: mydir: Permission denied
```

Hmm, okay, I guess I'm not in the `mygroup1` group, right? Wrong:

```
inger@server$> groups inger
inger: inger [a bunch of other groups] mygroup1 mygroup2 mygroup3
```

...confirming with getent

```
inger@server$> getent group mygroup1
mygroup1:*:1903:inger,[a bunch of other users]
```

...Maybe there's some mixup with the GID of `mygroup1`? Nope:

```
inger@server$> ls -nd mydir
drwxrwx--- 2 0 1903 4096 May 22 05:27 mydir
```

If I chown the group to `root:mygroup2`, I can get in just fine:

```
inger@server$> sudo -s
root@server:# chown root:mygroup2 mydir
root@server:#  ls -ld mydir
drwxrwx--- 2 root mygroup2 4096 Aug 15 09:44 mydir
root@server:# exit
inger@server$> cd mydir
^^ that works
```

There are no special ACLs overriding normal UNIX perms:

```
inger@server$> getfacl mydir
# file: mydir
# owner: root
# group: mygroup1
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

This directory doesn't have a special NFS mount or anything - it shares a mount with other directories, none of which have this problem, but they also aren't owned by `mygroup1`.

So, the problem appears to be *specific to this group.*

This problem was discovered this morning - members of `mygroup1` could get into `mydir` just fine yesterday.

We manage users and groups with FreeIPA, and yesterday I added some new users to the `mygroup1` group. But I added users to the `mygroup2` group as well, and there are no problems with that.

Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: I suppose there aren't any special ACLs set by `setfacl` in place that may override permissions? (Should have been denoted by a `+` in `ls` though)

Comment: @TobiasK good question. no special ACLs. I'll add that to my question, thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is also relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/389716/how-to-automatically-reconcile-etc-group-and-etc-gshadow - however for me it was always enough to just re-login after adding an user to a group.

Comment: Did you get added to the `mygroup1` group after logging in? Your groups are set when you login, you have to logout and back in again to pick up changes.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: What does the `id` command say your current groups are?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your brainstorming. `id` shows: `uid=1917(inger) gid=1917(inger) groups=1903(mygroup1)` and a bunch of other groups...so id and gid match.

Comment: also thanks for the reminder, @Barmar - I searched all of Stack Exchange hoping to get some hits off of either SU or U&L but got nothing of use. i'll try those specific exchanges and see what i can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation with certain NFS configurations where your group memberships after the 16th group are ignored when resolving permissions. Here is a good [writeup](http://www.xkyle.com/solving-the-nfs-16-group-limit-problem/) on it.

Comment: The question says **This directory doesn't have a special NFS mount or anything**. Does that mean it's *not* an NFS mount, or it *is* an NFS mount but not "special" (what are special NFS mounts?)?